# A function with big eigenvalues acting on the unit ball.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $B(0,1)=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2< 1\}$ denote the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $C$ denote a cylinder around the $z$-axis with radius $2$. Suppose that on each point $w$ in $B(0,1)$ we attach a pair of linearly independent vectors $ u_w,v_w$. Suppose now that we can find a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ which is continuously differentiable everywhere and whose total derivative, $D_wf$ at a point $w\in B(0,1)$ has as its two biggest eigenvalues $\lambda_u$ and $\lambda_v$ for which the corresponding eigenvectors are $u_w$ and $v_w$. Assume that the eigenvalues $\lambda_u$ and $\lambda_v$ corresponding to  those two vectors both satisfy $|\lambda_u|,|\lambda_v|>M$, where $M$ is a big number.

**Question**: Is it true that the image of the ball  $f(B(0,1))$ will necessarily intersect the cylinder $C$,  assuming the number $M$ is big enough?

Intuitively it seems to me that with all those assumptions our function $f$ stretches the unit ball  at two different directions locally by a lot so the answer to the question should be yes.

**Edit**: We can also assume that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

**Added later:**
If we also knew that the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_0$ is big,  meaning $|\lambda_0|>M$, then the answer would be yes. That is because in this case  if $\gamma$ is the shortest curve joining $f(0)$ with $\partial f(B(0,1))$ then 
$$
\operatorname{length}(\gamma)\geq M.$$ This can be proved as follows :
Let $\gamma_1=f^{-1}(\gamma)$ be the inverse image of $\gamma$ which is a curve joining $0$ with $\partial B(0,1)$. Then
\begin{align*}
 \operatorname{length}(\gamma)&=\int_{\gamma}|dx|=\int_{f(\gamma_1)}|dx|=\int_{0}^{1}\left|\left(f\left(\gamma_1(t)\right)\right)'\right|dt\\&=\int_{0}^{1}\left|D_{\gamma_1(t)}f\left(\frac{\gamma_1'(t)}{|\gamma_1'(t)|}\right)\right||\gamma_1(t)'|dt\\&\geq\int_{0}^{1}\inf_{|x|=1}\left|D_{\gamma_1(t)}f\left(x\right)\right||\gamma_1(t)'|dt\geq M\int_{0}^{1}|\gamma_1(t)'|dt\geq M
\end{align*}

Comment: what do you mean by the "biggest eigenvectors"? In what sense is one eigenvector "bigger" than another?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I wrote it a bit better now.

Comment: There is stupid counterexample if you have $f(0) \neq 0$, since you can translate a ball far away and then stretch it as much as you like.

Comment: @prosinac Yes you are right! So let us say instead that the cylinder has $f(0)$ as its center and not $0$. Or alternatively that $f(0)=0$.